# Not able to SSH using subprocess with identity file

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to ssh using python subprocess using the following command:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i %s/.ssh/anotherIdentity" % os.path.expanduser("~"), " user@%s" % host, command], 
shell=False, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am getting the error:

```
['Warning: Identity file  /Users/saurabh.araiyer/.ssh/anotherIdentity not accessible: No such file or directory.\n', 'Permission denied (publickey).
```

The identity file is present in the location, 
What could be the reason behind this?

Python version: 2.7.10 in Mac

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra space here in

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i %s/.ssh/anotherIdentity" % os.path.expanduser("~"), " user@%s" % host, command],
```

so if we remove the extra space after -i, it will work. Correct usage:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i%s/.ssh/anotherIdentity" % os.path.expanduser("~"), " user@%s" % host, command],
```

or separate the `-i` and argument to different parameters

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-i", "%s/.ssh/anotherIdentity" % os.path.expanduser("~"), " user@%s" % host, command],
```

Comment: OMG. The most unrelated error message to the problem. The identity file is accessible. The file does exist. There is no permission issues. Thank you.